# R: Extracting the strings/numeric inside the bracket as well as a sequence of strings inside squared bracket

Tags: regex, r, text-mining, tidyr, data-cleaning

I am running into some problem in separating the data into two or three columns.

The following is the strings I would like to process the following column

```
station "Park Rd & Holmead Pl NW (31602)"
```

What can I do to separate it into two columns:

```
station address   "Park Rd & Holmead Pl NW "             
station number    31602
```

In a similar fashion,
how could I separate the following strings?

```
station  "Park Rd & Holmead Pl NW (formerly 34th & Water St NW)"
```

into:

```
station         "Park Rd & Holmead Pl NW"                          
former station  "34th & Water St NW"
```

Anyone who is good with regular expression, please help me out!

Thanks!!

Comment: ....and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
# question 1
x <- "Park Rd & Holmead Pl NW (31602)"
strsplit(x, "\\(|)$")[[1]]

# question 2
x <- "Park Rd & Holmead Pl NW (formerly 34th & Water St NW)"
strsplit(x, "\\(formerly |)$")[[1]]
```

Comment: `strsplit` certainly would appear to be a reasonable start, but wouldn't you need to do _something_ with the second part?

Comment: For "the second part" please `dput` your data.frame